# get the latest records in an effective way

Tags: select, plsql, oracle10g, sql-order-by

I must get the latest records in my table. For this, first I select all records then I order them and get the latest 100 records. It costs a lot. I wonder is it a better way for this?

I am using oracle 10g.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with [tag:plsql]? Are you really using PL/SQL to do this?

Comment: Do this all in SQL! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add some condition if you know that those 100 records will always meet the criteria, e.g. load_date > '01-Jan-2012'

Comment: Of course, this will only help if there's an index on load_date.

Comment: yes there is an index but I am not using any date criteria, I have only count, it is like mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are doing this all in SQL?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM table
  ORDER BY modified_date DESC
)
WHERE rownum <= 100;
```

One thing you can do is create a descending index on 'modified_date':

```
CREATE INDEX table_modified_date_desc_idx on table(modified_date DESC);
```

Then your query should use this index to retrieve only the latest records. If it doesn't you may also have to re-gather statistics on this table.

Comment: Yes, I did like this. However, in this case, I select all records then I order them and get 100 records. It costs a lot :/

Comment: Have you created the descending order index?